# Launching Netflix iOS App from another iOS App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, netflix

I've found around the web you can use the nflx:// url scheme to launch the Netflix app. Has anyone worked out the params to actually land it on a specific movie or search?

Answer (score 5):

From [this thread](http://developer.netflix.com/forum/read/70098):

> Looks like Netflix does this already. Example URL:
>
> nflx://www.netflix.com/WiPlayer?shopperId=G-510cf375-e838-41c3-b3bd-1ab5ae98b667-1&movieid=1179468&trkid=1462433&episodeid=0&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netflix.com%2FWiPlayer%3Fmovieid%3D1179468%26trkid%3D1462433%26pbc%3Dtrue
>
> nlfx:// anything opens up the netflix app. Not sure where the
>   shopperId comes from. I replaced whatever netflix used with a new UUID
>   using uuidgen.
>
> In my case I simply tried using a nflx:// URL and using the movieid
>   parameter - this did not work correctly.

But also, more importantly:

> At this point, we aren't officially supporting any external launch points into the Netflix iPad application. If you suss them out yourselves and use them, the danger is that they may eventually go away.

Comment: Yep thanks, that's the page I referred too in my post. I need to search etc

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand the point of those answers: there is no publicly documented way to do this, and if you manage to find something it will probably break later. (This is why you're not allowed to use private APIs on the App Store.) Reach out to the Netflix folks to request this, or use their other APIs, but don't hack around with private stuff.